# Better keyboard to type '?' symbol

Tags: keyboard

I was wondering, is there any better keyboard for me to type to following '?' symbol. Now, using stock android keyboard, to type '?', I need to

1. Press and hold ',' key, a list of symbol choices will shown.
2. Hold and move my finger to '?'.
3. Release.

I feel not comfortable on step 2, as most of the time, my finger is quite dry. I found it is difficult for me to hold and move my dry finger on the screen. Is there any way I can.

1. Press ',' key, a list of choices will shown.
2. Click on '?'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In pre-2.2 stock keyboard, typing the ? is a two step process:

[image]
[image]

Alternatively, you can long press on `.` and a pop up menu will appear:

[image]
[image]

In 2.3 stock keyboard, the auto-correct bar will show common punctuations, including `?`:

[image]

The old two-step ways of using the `?123` page and long-pressing on the `.` still works, although when you long-press on `.` now you only need to slide your finger to the punctuations.

In Swype, you can long press on the letter `M` to produce `?`:

[image]

Alternatively, you can press `Sym` keyboard:

[image]
[image]

If you're using SwiftKey X Beta, the `?` has its own dedicated key in the main keyboard:

[image]

If you're using HTC keyboard, you can long-press on the letter `k`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Swiftkey](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey) is a keyboard that aims to reduce the amount of keys strokes you make by predicting the next word in a sentence based on your typing history - that means it gets better the more you use it.

In your case, it also has just one keypress to type a `?` as you can see below:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Swype would be your best bet, just swype the symbol to the spacebar and voila! You have your question mark.

http://www.swypeinc.com/i/basic-keypad.jpg

Here's a link for videos of the tricks you could do with swype: http://www.swypeinc.com/tips-tricks.html (Search for how to swype punctuation!)

If you want in, register from here: http://www.swypeinc.com/myswype.html

Best thing is it's free!

Comment: I guess Swype will actually be the the worst keyboard for OP since he had problems swiping on the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure if he has a problem with "holding and moving" or "swyping", they are similar but different animals altogether. I guess it's all up to him to decide which keyboard fits him best. :D By the way, very nice instructions, very well documented. :D

Comment: For anyone interested, it appears Swype is no longer available or maintained.

Answer (score 1):

[MessagEase](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.exideas.mekb) has the "?" symbol directly available in one-touch from the default screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press the "Sym" button, then press the "?" button, no dragging required.  You can also do a medium press of the button to get the symbol without the menu appearing (long press).  You'll see the symbol appear when you've held the button long enough for the medium press.

Comment: Sorry. But, what is "Sym" button?

Comment: In the stock keyboard, it's between the swype button on the left and the space bar.  If your stock keyboard isn't the same as in the swype tips videos that Cygnum linked, then you'll want to specify your Android version in the question.

Comment: I cannot c swype or sum button. i am using nexus s android 2.3

Comment: Then it doesn't appear that you're on the stock keyboard.

Comment: @B Mitch Swype is it's own keyboard and has a different layout and usage to the stock keyboard, see Lie Ryan's post for how differently some of the common English keyboards are layed out.

Comment: Thanks GAThrawn, since it came out of the box on G2, I had assumed it was the stock one.  I've got to stop assuming things.